# Difference between subject and individual by Marx

Tags: psychology, marx, concept

I would like to know the difference of the concepts of subject and individual philosophically speaking, I'm studying subjectivity theory in Marx and I have doubts about the difference between these concepts.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about why this difference might have become interesting or important to you? It might also help to specify your doubts in terms of particular concerns or questions

Answer (score 1):

Marx followed what we might call a *relational* epistemology and ontology. To quote a glossary definition of ["subject and object" from Marxists.org](https://www.marxists.org/glossary/terms/o/b.htm):

> In the dialectical theory of knowledge, the important thing is to understand the subject and object as a unity and to see both the activity of the subject (which had been developed by idealism – see Theses on Feuerbach No. 1) and the independent existence of the world of which the subject is a part (which had been emphasised by materialism).

For this reason, I think you will not find Marx or Marxists saying very much about human "individuals" as such. From a Marxian perspective, our common sense understanding and experience of existence as human individuals is a bit misleading, as it conceals the *unity* described above.

Comment: The unity of the contradicting notions but also their separation is dialectical. Marxism gives emphasis to the unity mostly for ideological reasons... (or perhaps they misinterpret dialectics).

Answer (score -2):

Not Marx's but Marxist writers' ideas lies on here a little bit. It may help.
http://jdeanicite.typepad.com/i_cite/2013/02/how-is-it-that-the-subject-becomes-an-individual.html

Comment: That may be a very useful link; however, it would be great if you could actually say something about it or summarize its content. As it stands, this is not an answer.